# how to set the value from a column to another based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have the following df:

```
subscription|amount| Total
a           |500   |
x           | 0    | 5000
x           |7500  | 5000
y           |7500  | 5000
y           | 0    | 5000
z           |7500  | 5000
z           | 0    | 5000
b           | 0    | 
b           |1000  |
```

I want to transfer the value of the 'total' to the 'amount' where there is already a value in the 'amount' column and of course in the 'total'.

I filtered:

```
df.loc[(df['total'].notnull()) & (df['amount']!=0)]
```

but couldn't transfer the value from total (5000) to the amount.

Desired Output:

```
subscription|amount| Total
a           |500   |
x           | 0    | 5000
x           |5000  | 5000
y           |5000  | 5000
y           | 0    | 5000
z           |5000  | 5000
z           | 0    | 5000
b           | 0    | 
b           |1000  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more solutions, if no problem if column is changed to floats - [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = (df['Total'].notnull()) & (df['amount']!=0)
```

---

```
df.loc[mask, 'amount'] = df['Total']

df['amount'] = np.where(mask, df['Total'], df['amount'])

print (df)
  subscription  amount   Total
0            a   500.0     NaN
1            x     0.0  5000.0
2            x  5000.0  5000.0
3            y  5000.0  5000.0
4            y     0.0  5000.0
5            z  5000.0  5000.0
6            z     0.0  5000.0
7            b     0.0     NaN
8            b  1000.0     NaN
```

Solutions with no change integer column to floats with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html), [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) or casting to `integers` with `np.where`:

```
df['amount'] = df['amount'].mask(mask, df['Total'])

df['amount'] = df['amount'].where(~mask, df['Total'])

df['amount'] = df['amount'].where(~mask, df['Total']).astype(int)

print (df)
  subscription  amount   Total
0            a     500     NaN
1            x       0  5000.0
2            x    5000  5000.0
3            y    5000  5000.0
4            y       0  5000.0
5            z    5000  5000.0
6            z       0  5000.0
7            b       0     NaN
8            b    1000     NaN
```